# Hadoop examples beside the word count

Tags: hadoop, word-count

I like to learn Hadoop applications in the real world scenarios. Currently most of the example only cover the word count problem, and no any example on industrial use case.

Are there other Hadoop examples, or Hadoop tutorials out there, that solve other problem beside the word count problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns for source code examples that are documented in the book "Map Reduce Design Patterns" by Miner and Shook.  I have tried them all and they all work in Hadoop using Cloudera's Training VMs.

Comment: The Map Reduce Design Patterns book is a very useful book and could be learnt  from many examples. It help us to understand how to apply design patterns on MapReduce. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a book that gives examples and brings simplicity and practicality to the real world!

- [Data Algorithms Recipes](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033950.do) for Scaling Up with Hadoop and Spark By Mahmoud Parsian